# How to compile BlackMagic SDK to FFMPEG

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

In Mac OS 10.13 I have installed FFMPEG via
brew install ffmpeg
I have downloaded the latest BlackMagic SDK from BlackMagic websit.

I am not sure how I can compile black magic SDK to my ffmpeg.

Here is the update

Manafs-MacBook-Pro:ffmpeg Manaf$ ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-decklink --extra-cflags=-I/Users/Manaf/Desktop/BM_SDK/Mac/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/Users/Manaf/Desktop/BM_SDK/Mac/include/

install prefix            /Users/Manaf/ffmpeg_build

source path               .

C compiler                gcc

C library

ARCH                      x86 (generic)

big-endian                no

runtime cpu detection     yes

standalone assembly       yes

x86 assembler             nasm

MMX enabled               yes

MMXEXT enabled            yes

3DNow! enabled            yes

3DNow! extended enabled   yes

SSE enabled               yes

SSSE3 enabled             yes

AESNI enabled             yes

AVX enabled               yes

AVX2 enabled              yes

AVX-512 enabled           yes

XOP enabled               yes

FMA3 enabled              yes

FMA4 enabled              yes

i686 features enabled     yes

CMOV is fast              yes

EBX available             yes

EBP available             yes

debug symbols             yes

strip symbols             yes

optimize for size         no

optimizations             yes

static                    yes

shared                    no

postprocessing support    yes

network support           yes

threading support         pthreads

safe bitstream reader     yes

texi2html enabled         yes

perl enabled              yes

pod2man enabled           yes

makeinfo enabled          yes

makeinfo supports HTML    no

External libraries: (lots of them I just removed them for this post)

External libraries providing hardware acceleration:(here too)
Libraries:(Here too)
Programs:ffmpeg         ffprobe

Enabled decoders:(here too- so many)

Enabled hwaccels:(here too)

Enabled parsers:(here too)

Enabled demuxers:(here too)

Enabled muxers:(here too)

Enabled protocols:(here too)

Enabled filters:(here too)

Enabled bsfs:(here too)

Enabled indevs:

avfoundation        decklink        lavfi

Enabled outdevs:

decklink

License: nonfree and unredistributable

libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged

libavcodec/parser_list.c is unchanged

libavcodec/bsf_list.c is unchanged

libavformat/demuxer_list.c is unchanged

libavformat/muxer_list.c is unchanged

libavdevice/indev_list.c is unchanged

libavdevice/outdev_list.c is unchanged

libavformat/protocol_list.c is unchanged

Manafs-MacBook-Pro:ffmpeg Manaf$ ffmpeg -devices

ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree

libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100

libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100

libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100

libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100

libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100

libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0

libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100

libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100

libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100

Devices:

D. = Demuxing supported

.E = Muxing supported

--

D  avfoundation    AVFoundation input device

D  lavfi           Libavfilter virtual input dev

Thanks,

./ffmpeg -devices

ffmpeg version N-90585-g46129b4044 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
configuration: --prefix=/Users/Manaf/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/Users/Manaf/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/Users/Manaf/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/Users/Manaf/bin --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-decklink --extra-cflags=-I/Users/Manaf/Desktop/BM_SDK/Mac/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/Users/Manaf/Desktop/BM_SDK/Mac/include/

libavutil      56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100

libavcodec     58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100

libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100

libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100

libavfilter     7. 14.100 /  7. 14.100

libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102

libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101

libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100

Devices:

D. = Demuxing supported

.E = Muxing supported

--

D  avfoundation    AVFoundation input device

DE decklink        Blackmagic DeckLink output

D  lavfi           Libavfilter virtual input device

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you should do a manual compiling, use these guidelines:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS

and add this to configure parameter:
`--enable-decklink` to enable Blackmagic DeckLink I/O support

Example `configure` line:

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-decklink --extra-cflags=-I/usr/src/ffmpeg/BMDL_SDK/SDK/Linux/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/src/ffmpeg/BMDL_SDK/SDK/Linux/include/`

You must need to fix paths according to your folders, especially for `--extra-cflags=` and `--extra-ldflags=..`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I have tried that, it seems its very old scripts does not support new Mac OS and Lam library missing and lots of other errors

Comment: Ok, I updated for more detailed answer. Check it again.

Comment: I followed the steps and I reach to the last step (your example above) ./Configure does not exist on the Blackmagic Folder that I got from Blackmgic website :(

Comment: `.. ./configure ..` is for the ffmpeg folder, you'll see there is a `configure` file, you just set the folders right. If configure succeeds then you can `make` and then `make install`.

Comment: I have tried that its seems like its started but still --enable-decklink is not not there, when I "make" I got lots of warning of Clang Wall I think and make install goes fine but also no decklink

Comment: `./configure` step MUST be successful, otherwise it guaranteed can't compile. Is there any error in configure ? if yes, post it here (update your question).

Comment: I have update it the question, please see that by the end of ./configure see "Enabled indevs" it has decklink but ffmpeg-devices does not show it

Comment: someone advice me to use ./ffmpeg I see the decklink now as output device, I tried to capture but no luck, updated the question again

Comment: Perhaps you should better use bmdtools, does same thing AFAIK and compiled separately: https://github.com/lu-zero/bmdtools

Comment: I finally managed to compile the SDK's and capture from decklink,  I was using the latest version of MacOS, BlacMagic desktop and BlacMagic SDK, I downgraded the OS to 10.10, BM desktop to 10.6 and BM SDK to 10.9.7 now and using ./ffmpeg :) it took hours of testing but the results really worth it. your answer give me a big hint thanks a lot.